# Why c++ is not used in L2/L3/L4 development projects

Tags: c++

I have been involved in numerous c++ projects mainly in the application domain pertaining to VOIP protocols. Now I have to move to L3 , L2 protocol development projects where I found 'C' is preferred language of choice for the L2/L3/L4 developers.

Now I am wondering expect device firmware related applications, why protocols are developed using stone age era language. Why ppl dont take the benefits of OOPS techniques? Will it be prudent if I try to convince them to switch to c++. Most of the developers working in the team are C experts and not comfortable with C++.

Comment: "Most of the developers working in the team are C experts and not comfortable with C++." That would be the top reason to use C.

Comment: Also, OOP isn't always beneficial.

Comment: C++ is not only about OOP. For example, there is a standard library, and templates, which can be extremely useful. It is a huge and complicated language though, so one cannot just "switch" to it. Some considerable investment in learning is usually required.

Comment: What exactly are L2/L3/L4 projects?

Comment: @RedX, I think he means project for protocol development as in [OSI layering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

Answer (score 5):

There are several reasons for continuing using C.

1. There are existing C projects. Who will pay for converting them into C++?
2. C++ compiler (of a good quality) is not available on every platform.
3. Psychological reason. When you pass and return objects by value, temp objects are created left and right. This is not ok for small systems. People do not really understand that passing and returning references completely solves this problem. There are other similar issues.
4. And finally. What is wrong with C? It works! (Do not fix what is not broken).

It is possible to write the same performant code on C++ as on C, but this requires better understanding, training, code control discipline. Common percetion is that these flaws are unavoidable.

Comment: Concerning point 3, most compilers implement copy ellision (RVO and NRVO), so temp objects are *not* created most of the time. So another psychological barrier is to stop always passing by reference.

Comment: @juanchopanza, you comment is at least unprofessional. What means "most compilers"? What is "most of the time"? There is fundamental difference between 50mhz microcontroller and 1.6ghz Core2.

Comment: I mean GCC as far as I can remember, VS (although I am not sure since when), clang. With GCC, I have tested with some ARM/OMAP processors too.If you know of one that doesn't implement RVO and NRVO I would be interested to know. I also didn't downvote, because I think point 1 is a very important one that is often neglected.

Comment: To point #1 - is not always required to convert existing C code to C++ because valid C is also valid C++. If conversion to OOP hierarchy is wanted then some work needs to be done, but can be done gradually.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I was participating in a project for Atmel 8-bit about 4 years ago. At that time there were no major C++ compilers for this chip. There were small companies that were selling something. For some  of them we found negative feedback, for others it was necessary to invest time in evaluation their compilers (and buying them) with unclear result. We decided to use C. I am not sure it was fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @deo, for 70% you are right. Some initial effort is always needed, even if it is not a rewrite. Even this effort can be enough for not doing anything.

Comment: @KirillKobelev That is interesting, I wonder if the situation has changed since then. But I would also be very reluctant to use a largely non-standard C++ compiler for anything professional.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I do not know the current situation. For Atmel most likely the situation has changed. But there are still hundreds of other less popular chips..

Comment: To your point#4: what I basically see not 'wrong' in C but rather uncomfortable is that it does not do anything for you but rather forces you to do everything yourself. In c++ you can get around this by relying on things that the compiler/standard library does for you and thus reduces the amount of work in the long run. I agree that using C++ especially in embedded systems needs more understanding how the language works, but when this understanding is achieved it greatly improves productivity and correctness without sacrificing performance when compared to pure C development.

Comment: Both the languages have their pros and cons. C being a small language can fit into the head of the programmer, but for large projects where the code size exceeds 100k lines of code isnt it much easier to manage code complexity with C++. Through increased use of code resuse productivity and reliablity is also increased.

Answer (score 4):

If you think of C as simply a "stone-age language," then I think you misunderstand why people continue to use it.  I like and use both C and C++.  I like them both for different reasons, and for different kinds of problems.

The C language presents a model of the computer that is both (mostly) complete and very easy to understand, with very few surprises.  C++ presents a very complex model, and requires the programmer to understand a lot of nuance to avoid nasty surprises.  The C++ compiler does a lot of stuff automatically (calling constructors, destructors, stack unwinding, etc.).  This is usually nice, but sometimes it interferes with tracking down bugs.  In general, I find that it's very easy to shoot yourself in the foot with both C and C++, but I find the resulting foot-surgery is much easier to do in C, simply because it's a simpler language model.

The C model of a computer is about as close to assembly as you can while still being reasonably portable.  The language does almost nothing automatically, and lets you do all kinds of crazy memory manipulations.  This allows for unsafe programming, but it also allows for very optimized programming in an environment with very few surprises.  It's very easy to tell exactly what a line of code does in C.  That is not true in C++, where the compiler can create and destroy temporary objects for you.  I've had C++ code where it took profiling to reveal that automatic destructors were eating a ton of cycles.  This never happens in C, where a line of code has very few surprises.  This is less of an issue today than it was in the past; C++ compilers have gotten a lot better at optimizing many of their temporaries away.  It can still be an issue, though, and especially in an embedded environment where memory (including stack space) is often tight.

Finally, code written in C++ often compiles **slowly**.  The culprits are usually templates, but eliminating templates often makes your C++ code look a lot like C.  And, I really cannot overstate how much this can affect productivity.  It kills productivity when your debug-fix-recompile-test cycle is limited by the compilation time.  Yes, I know and love pre-compiled headers, but they only do so much.

Don't get the impression that I'm anti-C++ here.  I like and use the language.  It's nice to have classes, smart pointers, std::vector, std::string, etc.  But there's a reason that C is alive and kicking.

For a different perspective, and one that is firmly anti-C++, you should at least skim over [Linus Torvald's](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/linus) perspective on C++.  His arguments are worth thinking about, even if you disagree with them.

Comment: I think slowness of compilation is mostly a problem when working with poor development environment which cleans and re-compiles everything every time without considering which files have changes and need recompiling. Usually debug takes place in 1-3 files at a time, re-compiling those should take place in few seconds unless there is excessive amounts of recursive templates or something.

Comment: Thorvalds is way off, and has caught himself in a catch-22 situation. He says that C++ sucks because he can't find any good C++ programmers. And that makes it true, because he has now scared away those he really needed.

Comment: @deo it depends quite a lot on what and where the problem is. If your bug touches code in a header, then all bets may be off. If your bug requires refactoring one or more classes, then your going to potentially recompile a large part of your project.

Comment: @BoPersson Torvalds holds strong opinions. You'd be hard pressed to argue that C++ programmers are what the Linux kernel and git are really lacking, though.

Comment: @sfstewman Agreed on that point. I still argue that compilation times are hardly a major problem in most debugging situations if/when the compilation environment re-compile only the needed parts. Even in those cases that it might cause some discomfort, I think that the benefits you get from using C++ features over C are greater than the compilation time penalty you get from using it.

Comment: I believe parts of the Linux kernel could benefit from real C++ instead of simulated OOP in C. But this is just theoretical, because he is not going to get the help anyway.

Comment: In our case a multi chassis router is under development with a properitery full blown networking OS (just like Linux) running on top it. It is not a small embedded project and there are no constraints on memory, and persistent storage. We have to develop the infrastrcture services and applications as well for this product.